# Content-Type for one file in multipart/form-data with HTTPie

Tags: httpie

I use [HTTPie](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie) to POST a
multipart/form-data request (passing the `-f` option).  It includes a
file field (using a `@` option).  The corresponding part of the
multipart request has a pseudo-header `Content-Disposition`, but does
not have a pseudo-header `Content-Type`.

How is it possible to add such a `Content-Type` for a specific file?

For completeness, here is what I send now (as shown by `-p B`):

```
--xyz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file.txt"

Hello, world!
This is the content of the file.

--xyz
```

but here is what I need to send:

```
--xyz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello, world!
This is the content of the file.

--xyz
```

Or to put it another way, like the CURL equivalent option: `-F "file=file.txt;type=text/plain"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just noticed that the documentation for `multipart/form-data` now reads like the following (at the end):

> When uploading files, their content type is inferred from the file
> name. You can manually override the inferred content type:
>
> $ http -f POST httpbin.org/post name='John Smith' cv@'~/files/data.bin;type=application/pdf'

I do not know when that happened, but it seems that now:

1. the "part `Content-Type`" is inferred automatically
2. it is possible to override it from the command line option

So all I was looking for! :-)

Ref: https://httpie.org/docs#file-upload-forms.

Comment: It gives me no such file or directory when I add the type part!

Comment: Are you sure to use a version that supports it?

Comment: thanks, it was a different version actually

Comment: seems to be apt package is outdated perhaps, when I installed it with snap it worked

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
http -f POST :8080/submit-file metadata=@metadata.json files@file1.jpeg files@file1.jpeg
```

This documentation helped me: https://httpie.org/doc#file-upload-forms

The `=@` makes httpie send it with content type `text/plain`.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason, I only see your response now. Thank you. But the point is not to have "text/plain", but to be able to set the Content Type. In your very example, I'd like to be able to ensure it is "application/json", and not "text/plain".

Comment: I got it wrong from the last sentence of the question. Curl equivalent: -F "file=file.txt;type=text/plain". I'm too out of context now to get back to it.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible with httpie. There is an [issue for it](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie/issues/271), with some pull requests to fix it, but none have been merged yet.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of :-( Thank you for the answer and the link!

Comment: As of five minutes ago, the master brunch supports content type detection ;)  $ pip install --upgrade https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie/tarball/master

Comment: @jkbrzt looks, like it still doesn't allow to set the Content-Type header for other parts of a multipart request, the way curl allows to do, e.g.: `curl --form "param=Test;type=text/plain" --form "file=@testFile.json;type=application/json"`. I send a request to a Spring-based REST application, and it checks for Content-Type headers of each multipart request param. If at least one is missing, it throws an exception.